# Text to PDF using PDFClown

Tags: c#, pdfclown

Please tell me how to convert text to PDF using PDF Clown library. I am using first time pdflown library. Is there any way to bind my string to PDF using this library.

Comment: If the library has a documentation, use it. If it doesn't then don't use the library.

Comment: Have a look at the [examples](https://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/dotNET/pdfclown.samples.cli/). There are text showing examples of variant complexity among them.

Comment: I have used itextsharp but in windows CE it fails to create PDF